# What is the expectation value of the position times momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Should I write the expectation of the position times momentum operator as:

$$\langle xp\rangle = \langle \psi|x (-i\hbar \partial_x) |\psi \rangle$$

or

$$\langle xp\rangle = \langle \psi| (-i\hbar \partial_x x) |\psi\rangle$$

Comment: Why would you think it's the second option?

Comment: Because $<xp>$ = $<px>$

Comment: Do not expect to find a real value though

Comment: @MathNewb Careful! $[x, p] = i \hbar$ tells you that in general $x p \neq p x$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact $xp$ is not self-adjoint, it can have non-real expectation values. But its symmetrized form $D=(1/2)(xp+px)$ is better behaved (it has a self-adjoint extension). It is the generator of dilatations which scales momenta and coordinates. The  complexification of ${\exp}[iDa]$ (i.e. $a$ becomes complex) is important for the study of the spectrum of a class of Schrödinger operators.

Comment: wow so deep, but I still couldn't derive this "non real expected value" even after using integration by parts

Comment: can you show me where you got this material from? im having trouble understanding the language "symmetrized form, generator, complexification..." thanks

Comment: There is quite some literature about this but probably at the moment somewhat above your level. But do not be discouraged, it will improve. One reference is the series "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics" by Reed and Simon, I think vo;ume III.

Answer (score 1):

in short the first way, but you can see this via using the position basis,

$$
<x|\psi> = \psi(x) , \ 1 = \int |x><x| \ dx, \ p|x> = |x> (-i \hbar \partial_x), \ <x|x'> =\delta(x-x') \ \rightarrow \\
<\psi|xp|\psi> = \int dx \ dx' <\psi|x><x| x p | x'><x'|\psi> = \int dx \ dx' \psi^*(x) x <x|p | x'> \psi(x') \\
=\int dx \ dx' \psi^*(x) x <x|x'>(-i \hbar \partial_{x'}) \psi(x') = -i \hbar \int dx \ dx' \psi^*(x) x \ \delta(x-x')\partial_{x'}\psi(x') \\
= -i \hbar \int dx \  \psi^*(x) \ (x \ \partial_{x}\psi(x) ) = <xp>_\psi
$$

typically you don't have to be this explicit but hopefully this helps. If this is a bit too much you can find more information in many introductory texts to QM such as Sakurai. Hope this helps